# How to use ACF to make a background image

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Hi There I am trying to make a background image be choose able via an ACF rule in my block editor via WordPress. I cannot get this to work for the life of me I must be missing something stupid any help will help here is what I have at the moment.

```
<div style="background-image: url(<?php echo get_field('my_background'));"></div>
```

In this code assume my_background is our ACF field  my ACF field is set up as a Image block set to URL but I cant make any leeway with this any help will be appreciated.

As menctioned this is being used in this block here

```
    <div style="<div id="mainPhoto" style="background-image: url(<?php the_field('$roomFacilitysBackgroundImage'); ?>);">">
                <h5>Room Facilities</h5>
                <div class="facilities facilities-column-50">
<?php
                    if  ($roomFacilitiesList3) {

                        foreach ($roomFacilitiesList3 as $roomFacilitiesList3 ) {
                            echo '<div>'.$roomFacilitiesList3.'</div>' ;
                        }
                    }
?>
                </div>
            </div>
```

This holds a outdated piece of background image to the one Above in the question

Comment: Where you are you using code? in a post template or in a loop?

Comment: @zillionera_dev It is being used at the beginning of a block of PHP code which does result in a loop happening but this is not apart of that this code is before anything like this happens. here is the entire block if it helps I have updated the question with the block it is apart of

Comment: If you are using this code in a post template or in a post loop then it should work otherwise you have to pass the post_id in "get_field" function.

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/

Comment: also make sure that ACF image fields Return Format is image url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you write

`<div style="background-image : url(<?php the_field('$youVarName'); ?>)> "`

try with :

```
$yourImageUrl = get_field('nameOfTheField);
style ='background-image:' url(<?= $yourImageUrl ?>)
```

if it's still don't work try to dump `$yourImageUrl`if it's not defined
there is 2 option :

1. you write the wrong field name
2. you'r not in the right context then try `get_field('nameOfTheField','Post_Or_PostID')`where `Post_Or_PostID`is where the field come from (post, option page ,....)
3. option it's good in php but you'r div is to small to display the background